# Группировка букв по принципу Фибоначчи

Tags: c++, алгоритм, числа-фибоначчи

Есть файл `Vhidniy.txt`, который забит символами. С него считать количество букв и погруппировать их по Фибоначчи. Вывести кол-во букв и группированные буквы в отдельный файл `Result.txt`.

Может, это глупо, но не могу записать буквы в массив и связать написанный код Фибоначчи с основной программой. Очень нужно выполнить данное задание, а голова совсем не варит. Помогите, пожалуйста, закончить программу и объяснить ошибки.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
void main()
{
    FILE *f1 = NULL;

    if(!(f1 = fopen("F:\\Vihidniy.txt", "r")))
    {
        printf("Error! Cannot open file");
        getch();
        return;
    }
    FILE *f2 = NULL;

    if(!(f1 = fopen("F:\\Result.txt", "w")))
    {
        printf("Error! Cannot open file 2");
        getch();
        return;
    }

    int count = 0;
    while(!feof(f1))
    {
        count++;
    }
    char *all = new char[count];

    while(!feof(f1))
    {
        fscanf(f1, "%c\n", all[i]);
        if(isalpha(all[i])){ int countl++; fprintf(f2, "\n\n %d\n", all[i]); }
    }


    char *l = new char[countl];

    while(!feof(f1))
    {
        fscanf(f1, "%c\n", all[i]);
        if(isalpha(all[i])){ l[i] = all[i] }
    }

    printf("\n\n Kilkist liter:%d\n", count);
    fprintf(f2, "\n\n Kilkist liter:%d\n", count)
        fclose(f1);
    fclose(f2);
    getch();
}
///////////////////////////////
int sf = 2 //сумма чисел Фибоначи
int count;
int f1 = 1, f2 = 1, f3;
printf("%d\n%d\n", all[1], all[2]);
do{
    f3 = f1+f2
        sf += f3;
    if(sf <=count)
        for(int i = sf-f3; i<sf; i++)
            printf("%c\t", all[i])
    else
    for(int i = sf-f3; i<count; i++)
        printf("%c\t", all[i])


        f1 = f2;
    f2 = f3;
} while(sf < count);
```

Comment: «погруппировать их по Фибоначчи» — это как?

Comment: Честно,  я не знаю, в задании не сказано. Но я нашел код для Фибоначчи , и не знаю что с ним делать)

Comment: Чего то тоне хватает, но в упор не понимаю чего ( помогите пожалуйста мне очень нужен этот код

Comment: Ну так уточнили бы у преподавателя. Ряд Фибоначчи это числовой ряд, где каждое последующее число равно сумме двух предыдущих. Единственно, как это можно приклеить к символам, так это склеивать строки из символов. Но как-то это очень странно.

Comment: Как раз я и уточнил,  а мне ответили загугли и все)

Comment: Я понимаю, что такое последовать. Фибоначчи: 1,1,2,3,5,8...,но как сделать с буквами (((

Comment: Последовать носить 1,1,2,3... это ясно,но буквы

Comment: А вы могли бы помочь с реализацией вашего метода группировки по строкам, уж очень надо, скоро зачет а осталась только эта лаба. Уже 2 неделю с ним бьюсь и никак...

Comment: [Вот](http://forum.vingrad.ru/topic-351233.html) ещё один от Вашего преподавателя, похоже. Правда кроме него, видимо, никто не понимает, что значит группировать символы по Фибоначчи. Можете ему сказать, что гугл не знает этого метода :)

Comment: Ну это не мой метод, это просто единственное, что приходит в голову: допустим есть файл содержащий: "abcdefg", тогда последовательность будет следующая: `a`, `b`, `ab`, `abc`, `abcd` и т.д.

Comment: @craftyperson я думаю, что ответить на вопрос "Что значит «погруппировать символы по Фибоначчи»" могут только два человека - ваш преподаватель и сам Фибоначчи. Фибоначчи уже умер, поэтому у кого об этом спросить - ответ очевиден.

Comment: И все же, как бы это ни нагло звучало, я это понимаю) могли бы Вы написать реализацию. Другого выхода нет, а у преподавания уже спрашивал.....

Comment: Код исходный есть, хотя и бредовый,  судя по всему. Единственному попалось такое задание. Помогите пожалуйста,  буду презнателен)

Comment: @craftyperson написать реализацию чего? Того, что никто не понимает кроме вашего препода?

Comment: Понимаю Вас, потому и тут. Задание не поменять.  А мне говорят, что это простенькое задание. Вот так и бьюсь уже длительный перилд

Comment: @craftyperson, бегите от такого преподавателя. А если серьезно, то попросите преподавателя показать пример: входные данные и результат.

Comment: Реализация Фибоначчи -его подсказка

Comment: А дальше, как бы все ясно) должно быть0

Comment: Даже похожего ничего нету)

Comment: Подсчет длины файла посимвольным считыванием, это мощно :) "Код Фибоначчи" тоже весьма странный. Может хотя бы задание процитируешь полностью и точно, а не в перепеве Рабиновича?

Comment: Дан файл с разными символами. Подсчитать количество букв в нем, вывести это кол-во в другой файл. Буквы из первого файла записать во второй погруппированные по принципу последовательности Фибоначчи .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по гуглу и мытарствам тех, кто получил эту же задачу до вас, преподаватель надеется получить символы, сгруппированные в пачки размером в числа из последовательности Фибоначчи (он переворачивается в гробу от такого, наверное).

Для этого надо при выводе считать последовательность Фибоначчи, и вставлять пробелы или переносы в нужных местах.

Если придерживаться вашего стиля кода, решение примерно такое:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<ctype.h>

int Fibonacci(int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return 0;
    else if (n == 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return (Fibonacci(n - 1) + Fibonacci(n - 2));
}

void main()
{
    FILE *f1 = NULL;

    if (!(f1 = fopen("c:\\temp\\in.txt", "r")))
    {
        printf("Error! Cannot open file");
        getch();
        return;
    }

    fseek(f1, 0, SEEK_END);
    int fileLength = (unsigned long)ftell(f1);
    fseek(f1, 0, SEEK_SET);

    char *all = new char[fileLength];
    int total = 0;

    while (!feof(f1))
    {
        char c;
        fscanf(f1, "%c", &c);
        if (isalpha(c))
        { 
            all[total++] = c;
        }
    }

    fclose(f1);

    FILE *f2 = NULL;

    if (!(f2 = fopen("c:\\temp\\Result.txt", "w")))
    {
        printf("Error! Cannot open file 2");
        getch();
        return;
    }

    printf("Kilkist liter: %d\n", total);
    fprintf(f2, "Kilkist liter: %d\n", total);

    int fibindex = 1;
    int currentFib = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < total; i++)
    {
        printf("%c", all[i]);
        fprintf(f2, "%c", all[i]);
        currentFib--;
        if (currentFib == 0)
        {
            currentFib = Fibonacci(++fibindex);
            printf("\n");
            fprintf(f2, "\n");
        }
    }

    fclose(f2);
}
```

З.Ы. угадаю город по преподавателю. Черкассы?

Comment: @craftyperson [погуглил](http://www.programmersforum.ru/showthread.php?t=198619). вместо плюса можете отметить ответ как правильный - серая V рядом с кнопками вверх вниз слева от ответа. и не спамьте комментариями - вам надо не радоваться, а грустить, с такими преподавателями )

Comment: учту Ваш совет)